# Play Framework: Form data not passed

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to create a login page based on the play framework sample 'zentask'.

When I try submitting the form in the login page, user_name and user_pass are null.

Command Prompt Output:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/smgts2
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
null null
```

Application.java:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import static play.data.Form.*;

import models.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    // -- Authentication

    public static class Login {

        public String user_name;
        public String user_pass;

        public String validate() {
            if(Accounts.authenticate(user_name, user_pass) == null) {
                return "Invalid user or password";
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Login page.
     */
    public static Result login() {
        return ok(
            login.render(form(Login.class))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle login form submission.
     */

    public static Result authenticate() {
        Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(loginForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
        } else {
            session("user_name", loginForm.get().user_name);
            return redirect(
                routes.Home.index()
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout and clean the session.
     */

    public static Result logout() {
        session().clear();
        flash("success", "You've been logged out");
        return redirect(
            routes.Application.login()
        );
    }
}
```

login.scala.html

```
@(form: Form[Application.Login])

@main(Html("School Management System")) {
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    </style>

    @helper.form(routes.Application.authenticate, 'class -> "form-signin") {

            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign-in to SMGTS</h2>

            @if(form.hasGlobalErrors) { 
                <p class="text-error">
                    @form.globalError.message
                </p>
            }

            @if(flash.contains("success")) {
                <p class="text-success">
                    @flash.get("success")
                </p>
            }

            <p>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" value='@form("user_name").value'>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="password" class="input-block-level" name="user_pass" placeholder="Password">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </p>


}
}
```

Routes File:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Home.index()

# Authentication
GET     /login                      controllers.Application.login()
POST    /login                      controllers.Application.authenticate()
GET     /logout                     controllers.Application.logout()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Accounts.java (Model Class):

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_account")
public class Accounts extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    public Long acc_id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String user_name;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String user_pass;

    @Constraints.Required
    public int group_id;

    // Queries

    public static Finder<Long,Accounts> find = new Finder<Long,Accounts>(Long.class, Accounts.class);

    public static Accounts authenticate(String user_name, String user_pass) {

        System.out.println(user_name + " " + user_pass); // Check if form data is passed.

        return find.where()
            .eq("user_name", user_name)
            .eq("user_pass", user_pass)
            .findUnique();

    }

}

I've been checking if the variable names in Application.java and they're the same with the input fields in login.scala.html.
```

Comment: Where in your code that you put something like `Logger.debug()` or `System.out.print()` that produce `null` value for `user_name` and `user_pass`. When I tried your code provided above, it seems fine. It will not produce `null` value after the `login` form is submitted with non-`null` value.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code. Reedited my post.

I've inserted `"System.out.println("user_name + " " user_pass");"` inside the model class which is `Accounts.java` -> `public static Accounts authenticate`.

I am still trying to edit the code, entered admin/admin in the fields but i ended up still having nulls in the output.

Comment: I've actually uploaded it on a repo in github if it would make it easier. Here's the link: https://github.com/gscruz/smgts2-git

Comment: I have tried your code on your github repository, and I also found that your code is fine. To be note here, I only modifying the datasource to use POSTGRESQL because I don't install MYSQL in my computer. Are you still have the problem occured?

Comment: Yea, same codes. Clueless why I'm getting null. I'll have to rework the whole thing.

Comment: Okay good luck friend.. :) By the way, I was tried your code on Windows 7 OS, Java 1.7, and Play!Framework 2.1.1, IntellijIDEA 12 Ultimate as source code editor, and running it from Play SBT console.

Comment: I have the same problem with a test app I just created. And I am doing exaclty the same in another app where it is working. The form data is actually available in the loginForm object that is retrieved from the request, but the loginForm.get() doesn´t pass them along (to the Login object).

Comment: HI again. I have now verified that my code gives to different answers on the "bindFromRequest" call on the form object in my Action that handles the post of the loginform. My Windows/jdk7/Play 2.1.0/SCala 2.10.0 environment works fine, while my mac/jdk1.6/Play 2.1.0/Scala 2.10.0 environment gives null values on my "loginForm"-object that is bound from the request. The code I am using is cloned from the same git repo. I am about to look further into this later...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try running play clean. It should magically fix it!

Comment: Also make sure the fields that the form is trying to inflate are public.. spent hours figuring that out.

Comment: "sbt clean" helped me too, so just wanted to put this here, in case someone is searching the answer as well.

Comment: It is weird. I was testing my form, which was working but suddenly stopped working

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same issue while working trough the book "Play for Java". I was working with Play 2.5.x and the examples worked with 2.2.x. After hours of searching for the solution, comparing with other examples I finally found the solution:

**Missing setters and getters in the model class.**

After I added the getters and setters the Form data finally got passed.

Alternative solution: [PlayEnhancer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayEnhancer)